# laravel 5.5 | old() empty in view unless $request->flash() used

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I've run into an odd issue where the helper function `old()` always returns null in a blade view unless `$request->flash()` is used prior to loading the view. I have never had to do this when using laravel in the past. Did something change or is there something that I have forgotten to set/configure. Below is a simple example of the behavior:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function(){

  return view('testView');

});

Route::post('/test', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

  $request->flash(); // if uncommented old() works, if commented old() does not work
  return view('testView');

});
```

**form in testView.blade.php**

```
<form action="/test" method="POST">

  {{csrf_field()}}

  <input type="hidden" name="test001" value="001"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="test002" value="002"/>

  <div class="">
    {{old('test001')}}
    <br/>
    {{old('test002')}}
  </div>

  <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

**after form submitted without `$request->flash()`**

[image]

**after form submitted with `$request->flash()`**

[image]

**EDIT**

Thinking this might have something to do with using a single route name for both post and get methods, the form was changed so to submit via get, and the issue persists. For example:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function(function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

  return view('testView');

});
```

**form in testView.blade.php**

```
<form action="/test" method="GET">

  <input type="hidden" name="test001" value="001"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="test002" value="002"/>

  <div class="">
    {{old('test001')}}
    <br/>
    {{old('test002')}}
  </div>

  <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `redirect back()` instead of loading view directly in a `post` method.

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

You need to `flash` request data to put `old input` into session, otherwise `old()` will return empty result. See official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#old-input) here.

Comment: This got me thinking about whether or not we should actually be using POST here and concluded it made more sense to use GET. When changing the form to submit via get and removing the post route, the same behavior is happening. Which I find rather odd. I have made an edit to my question to show what has been changed.

Comment: you are posting from with a get method?? whats the reason?? if you really want to use get, then you should use `<a></a>` tag

Comment: you could use route match for this purpose as you want to use same url for get and post.

Comment: as stated above, we don't want to use post. The edit shows where we have updated the form to submit via get, and the issue persists. I can't say I follow what you mean when you say we should use `<a></a>` tags. What I've posted is only an example of what's happening. Our actual form contains form inputs that users use as a way to filter search results.

Comment: somehow you need to make your old input available in your view, that's the reason you need to flash request data to put this into session, otherwise there is no data in session means no old input. `withInput()` do excatly same works when redirecting back to a url.

Comment: I might have just had a moment of clarity. If validation were being done on these form inputs, and that validation failed, does the request class then automatically place the old input values into the session before it redirects back?

Comment: yes, if you use laravel default validation `validate()`, or you may redirect like in my answer.